# javascript access web-based script on button click

Tags: javascript, function

How would I go about accessing a web-based script.  I don't know if I'm wording that correctly.  I just want to be able to click a button and run the function.  That's not the issue.  The issue is how do I go about putting it in a function.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://wwww.blah.com/blah?blah=blah"></script>
```

how would i get that to run on button click?  I've tried every which way to put it in a function and call the function.  No luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var buildScript = function (url, optionalCallback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script"),
        parent = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentElement;

    script.onload = optionalCallback;
    script.src = url;
    parent.appendChild(script);
};


var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
button.onclick = function () { buildScript("//url.to.site/file.js"); };
```

Or optionally:

```
button.onclick = function () {
    buildScript("//url.to.site/file.js", function () {
        function_from_loaded_script();
    });
};
```

If you need it to do other stuff, you might need to be more specific.

Comment: One quick word of caution, if you're looking to support old versions of IE: you'll have to listen for `onreadystatechange`, instead of `onload`.  Feel Feel free to use both - practically all other browsers will just ignore the other function.  If you aren't trying to do this on 10+ year old IE browsers, then forget about it.